# Empty tuple as argument to except in python

Tags: python, exception, tuples, except

I'm writing a utility module and trying to make it as generic as possible, and I'm trying to work out what the behavior would be here:

```
for i in xrange(num_tries):
  try:
    return func(*args, **kwards)
  except exceptions as e: 
    continue
```

I understand that

```
except:
```

Will catch ALL exceptions, and that

```
except (some, tuple, of, exceptions) as e:
```

Will catch those 4 exceptions,

But what is the behavior of an empty tuple? Does it simply catch

1. No exceptions
2. All exceptions

My guess is 1, but I can't think of quick way to test it. My thinking is that except with no parameters after would be except None, but an empty tuple would just be like saying "catch everything in this list", but there's nothing in the list so nothing is caught.

Thanks!

Comment: A quick way to test it would be to just raise a bunch of different exceptions in your `try` block ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 1: no exceptions, in Python 2 and in Python 3.

```
exceptions = ()
try:
    a = 1 / 0
except exceptions as e:
    print ("the answer is 2")

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<pyshell#38>", line 2, in <module>
a = 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

If you want to the behaviour of answer 2 when the list of exceptions is empty, you can do

```
except exceptions or (Exception,) as e:
```